# Some product are not showing up at front end in magento

Tags: magento, csv, upload, product

I am uploading product on my web site via csv using magmi. Everything was going fine.

But one time i made a mistake while uploading the products via `CSV`.

The products get uploaded but have not been assigned to corresponding  categories. I again uploaded the file.product has been assigned to categories and when i click on categories I can see them

But I can not see them under catalog and at front end

Answer (score 0):

make sure the product is enabled, and is not "out of stock". Usually imported products (at least in my experience) are imported in a disabled state with an available quantity of 0.

Also depending on your caching options, you may have to rebuild the indexes for the categories to show the product.

Comment: I did everything you have asked still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Below Possibilities:-

(1). Check that Product "status" is set to "Enabled".

(2). check that product is not set to visible "Not Visible Individually"

(3). Also check that product is set to "In stock" in Inventory.

So those are the possibilities that can affect the product display at front-end.